# How can I prove a Measurable function

Tags: measure-theory

$(\Omega,R\mathcal)$is a measure space.

$(f_j)_j,j\in$$N$ is a sequence of  non-negative measurable functions $(f_j):\Omega\to [0,\infty]$.
How can I prove that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty f_j$ is measurable ?

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\sum_{j}f_{j}=\sup_{n}S_{n}$, where $S_{n}=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n}f_{j}$, it should be easy to prove that each $S_{n}$ is measurable and the supremum of measurable functions is measurable.